# jHipster api with http session authentication not working for ionic app

Tags: java, angularjs, session, jhipster, ionic2

**Use Case**

I am trying to connect jHipster generated application with ionic 2 app. I am using http session authentication

**Overview of the issue**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.14:8081//vconnect/api/countries. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.4:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

**JHipster configuration, a .yo-rc.json file generated in the root folder**

```
{
"generator-jhipster": {
"jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
"baseName": "vconnect",
"packageName": "com.zenfact.vconnect",
"packageFolder": "com/zenfact/vconnect",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "session",
"hibernateCache": "ehcache",
"clusteredHttpSession": "no",
"websocket": "no",
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSocialSignIn": false,
"rememberMeKey": "559bbe3167552d040ba24d16506d389a7ba851c3",
"useSass": false,
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
"gatling"
],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
"en",
"zh-cn",
"fr",
"hi",
"ja"
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research I found that mobile apps do not play well with HTTP session authentication.

So I have recreated jhipster project with Oauth2 authentication which seems to work fine with ionic app that I am developing.

and the **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header** issue is solved by un-commenting **cors** in **application.yml**.